# Image Classification Pytorch

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, pytorch

How to decide number of layers and final model in CNN to increase the accuracy of the prediction.
I am classifying images and currently getting 65% accuracy with simple model how should I enhance it to achieve maximum accuracy.
(Pytorch)

Answer (score 0):

I would say three things.

1) check torchvision.models [link](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/models.html) there you can find pretrained great models which will give you great performance if you set layers to don't require gradients and just modify final layer to have correct number of classes

2) play with transformations when you are loading images [link](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/transforms.html) this can help you

3) play with number of last layers, different optimizer and try scheduler [link](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/optim.html#how-to-adjust-learning-rate) (this will adjust learning rate during training for better fit)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I don't know what dataset you are working on but try if you can get more dat or do some augmentationa and increase number of samples.

Comment: Also after you are done with training final layers enable gradients for whole network and train it with low learning rate. It also helps little bit.